# Script or way to Log out all users (WinServer 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access, logoff

How would i go about logging off or shutting down all of the computers (Windows XP) just in my ICT suite using a script or other method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a batch file to run the [dos shutdown command](http://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm) remotely.  There is also the psshutdown command within the [pstools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) suite.

It would look something like this:

```
psshutdown.exe \\comp1 -o
psshutdown.exe \\comp2 -o
```

Which you can tie into a scheduled task.  Look through the command parameters and try it out until your fairly confident the commands will do what you want them to.